# SVN precommit transaction details on remote system

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

SVN precommit hook provides a transaction ID. Using svnlook, the details of the transaction may be fetched at the SVN Server machine.

```
svnlook changed -t *Tr-ID* *RepoPath*
```

Is there a way that transaction details may be fetched at a remote machine (machine different from SVN Server machine) using the transaction ID provided to precommit hook script (the script shall keep the commit waiting while the remote machine fetches the details)?